# how to concat 2 pandas dataframe based on time ranges

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have two dataframe and I would like to concat them based on time ranges
for example

dataframe A

```
user   timestamp    product
 A      2015/3/13      1
 B      2015/3/15      2
```

dataframe B

```
 user      time     behavior
   A     2015/3/1      2
   A     2015/3/8      3
   A     2015/3/13     1
   B     2015/3/1      2
```

I would like to concat 2 dataframe as below ( frame B left join to frame A)
column "timestamp1" is 7 days before column "timestamp"
for example when timestamp is 3/13 , then 3/6-13  is in the range
otherwise dont concat

```
user   timestamp    product        time1       behavior 
 A      2015/3/13      1          2015/3/8        3
 A      2015/3/13      1          2015/3/13       1
 B      2015/3/15      2            NaN          NaN
```

the sql code would look like

```
select * from 
B left join  A
on user
where B.time >= A.timestamp - 7  &  B.time <= A.timestamp 

##WHERE B.time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(B.time, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND A.timestamp ;
```

how can we make this on python?

can only think of the following and dont know how to work with the time..

```
new = pd.merge(A, B, on='user', how='left')
```

thanks and sorry..

Comment: Are your time/timestamp fields formatted to pandas datetime?

Comment: do you want rows that fall in the same week of the year to be joined or are dates in the column 'timestamp' always the reference in the sense that they define the end points of the weeks?

Answer (score 2):

The few steps required to solve this-

```
from datetime import timedelta
```

First,convert your timestamps to pandas datetime. (df1 refers to Dataframe A and df2 refers to Dataframe B)

```
df1[['time']]=df1[['timestamp']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df2[['time']]=df2[['time']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Merge as follows: (Based on your final dataset i think your left join is more of a right join)

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left')
```

Get your final df:

```
df4 = df3[(df3.time>=df3.timestamp-timedelta(days=7)) & (df3.time<=df3.timestamp)]
```

The row containing nan is missing and this is because of the way conditional joins are done in pandas.

Condtional joins are not a feature of pandas yet. A way to get past that is by doing filtering post a join.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution that relies on two merges - first, to narrow down `dataframe B` (`df2`), and then to produce the desired output:

We can read in the example dataframes with `read_clipboard()`:

```
import pandas as pd

# copy dataframe A data, then:
df1 = pd.read_clipboard(parse_dates=['timestamp'])

# copy dataframe B data, then:
df2 = pd.read_clipboard(parse_dates=['time'])
```

Merge and filter:

```
# left merge df2, df1
tmp = df2.merge(df1, on='user', how='left')

# then drop rows which disqualify based on timestamp
mask = tmp.time < (tmp.timestamp - pd.Timedelta(days=7))
tmp.loc[mask, ['time', 'behavior']] = None
tmp = tmp.dropna(subset=['time']).drop(['timestamp','product'], axis=1)

# now perform final merge
merged = df1.merge(tmp, on='user', how='left')
```

Output:

```
  user  timestamp  product       time  behavior
0    A 2015-03-13        1 2015-03-08       3.0
1    A 2015-03-13        1 2015-03-13       1.0
2    B 2015-03-15        2        NaT       NaN
```